# how to regenerate the iOS and Android folders in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have removed both android and iOS folders after I detached, is there any way that I can bring back both android and iOS folders?

My app is detached from expo, is there a way that I can regenerate those two folders without having to upgrade the app.

Comment: react-native upgrade leads me into this error: react-native version in "package.json" (https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-26.0.0.tar.gz) doesn't match the installed version in "node_modules" (0.54.2

Comment: does this have any solution or shall I have to start once again from beginning creating the app on macOS so I have iOS included as well?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to start with a new project without expo and copy all components (react-native init AwesomeProject).
After I detached my project from expo I still had a lot of problems caused by expo. Especially the gradle config in android was a mess because of different versions (react-native-svg for example, which is standard in expo, but outdated).

And after starting new the project size decreased around 12MB...
Starting new took me around 2 hours, messing around with expo days...

Did you use some dependencies from expo in your project?

Comment: i cant start new with react-native init, as I need to use some Expo Api, I solved the problem by just running expo detach over my detached project and it is working fine, it created ios and android folder!